# Two-way communication using AF_UNIX socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'd like to implement the example from [python official documentation on socket module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) using `AF_UNIX` socket instead of `AF_INET`. So here's how server code looks now:

```
import socket
import os

filename = '/tmp/mysock'
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
sock.bind(filename)
while 1:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print 'Received', repr(data)
    if not data:
        break
    sock.sendall(data)
sock.close()
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somecode/server.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = sock.recv(2048)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOCK_STREAM is a stateful socket type, so any connection must first be acknowledged by a listening socket and then new dynamic socket (connection) is used for sending and receiving instead. You can't just receive from listening socket.

Basically you forgot to call `sock.listen()` on socket after binding and `connection, address = sock.accept()`, which blocks until a connection is established and then returns tuple with new socket (connection) and client address. Then simply use `connection.recv()`. This is universal for UNIX sockets and TCP/IP sockets.

For example have a look [here](http://wiki.unixh4cks.com/index.php/Python_:_Read_message_from_Unix_Domain_Socket_and_post_them_on_IRC_chatroom).

Comment: Thanks! Now I finally got it. I was confused by some examples that used `SOCK_DGRAM`. They don't need `listen` and `accept` methods.